# Any workarounds for image resizing in Craft 2.5 Redactor II?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, assets, redactor, image

Since imageResizable was deprecated for some apparent reason which I have no idea why they would do that. Does anyone know of a workaround or a plugin/config setting to enable this again?

Comment: Agree with this 100%, not sure why they removed the ability to resize an image, they should make it a plugin. I emailed the dev and never got a response.

Answer (score 2):

The only really workable solution I've found is to downgrade Redactor. Fortunately Pixel & Tonic have made this fairly painless with a plugin:

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI